# MySql update a second tableb automatically when a record is inserted into tablea

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I automatically update a second table `tableb` with a value from `tablea`, when a row is inserted into `tablea`, without any stored procedures or other things.

For example, if a row were to be inserted into tablea here, I'd like to update all the rows in `tableb` with the `itemId` from `tablea` where `itemTempId` in `tableb` is the same as the one in `tablea`

Both tables are type MyIsam

**Before insert into tablea**

```
tablea

"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemName"
-       -           -               -    
tableb    

"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName"
"1"     \N          "T001"          "front.jpg"
"2"     \N          "T001"          "side-left.jpg"
"3"     \N          "T001"          "side-right.jpg"
"4"     \N          "T001"          "back.jpg"
```

**After insert into tablea**

```
tablea

"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemName"
"1"     "US01"      "T001"          "Samsung Galaxy Note 5"    

tableb //updated with the itemId from tablea where itemTempId are the same  

"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName"
"1"     "US01"      "T001"          "front.jpg"
"2"     "US01"      "T001"          "side-left.jpg"
"3"     "US01"      "T001"          "side-right.jpg"
"4"     "US01"      "T001"          "back.jpg"
```

Comment: I don't know how you can do it without using a `Trigger`.

Comment: @Norman are you sure even you dont want to use any Trigger or any sql?

Comment: If the tables were INNODB, would this be possible? With foreign keys?

Comment: @prashantthakre I currently do it with php and sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TRIGGER` to update `tableb` after you've inserted a row in `tablea` :

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON tablea
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE tableb SET itemId = NEW.itemID WHERE itemTempID = NEW.itemTempID;
```

I think you can't do it without `TRIGGER`, and like this, it's really simple.

Comment: I was trying something like this, but wonder why this wont update the second table `update amga a, amgb b set a.itemId = a.id, b.itemId = a.itemId 
where a.itemId = 0 and a.itemTempId = 'T001'`;

Comment: "I was trying something like this" ? That's not something like this, you're are not creating a trigger. Your query won't be executed for each `insert` on `tablea`

Comment: No. I plan on running it manually using php after php does the insert.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have an access to the database creation ? Or all you can do is inserting in it ?

Comment: i have access to the database creation.

Comment: Ok, so after all the tables creations create this Trigger like this. Then you just have to INSERT INTO tablea (with php or anything else) and you'll see tableb updated.